# File upload with extjs4

Tags: file-upload, extjs4

i am working on Extjs4 file upload control. i have view with file upload control as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.Content', 
{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.ContentView'
              ],
    id:'ContentId',
    alias:'widget.Content',
    enctype : 'multipart/form-data', 
    title:'This day in a history',
    items:[

    {
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        hideLabel: true,
        emptyText: 'Select a file to upload...',
        //inputType: 'file',
        id: 'upfile',
        width: 220
}],
   buttons: [{
        xtype : 'button',
        fieldlabel:'upload',
        action:'upload',
        name:'upload',
        text: 'Upload',
        formBind:'true'

    }]
});
```

And corresponding action in controller is-

```
getUpload : function() {

        var file10 = Ext.getCmp('ContentId').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
            fileobj=oFREvent.target.result;
            console.log(oFREvent.target.result);

        };
        }
    });
```

So above controller's function is retriving uploaded file and displaying it in encoded format inside reader's onload function. i.e. "console.log(oFREvent.target.result);" line is displaying uploaded file's data in encoded format in console. I need to send this file to server side. So i am passing above fileobj as parameter to store as-

```
var storeObj=this.getStore('kp.DnycontentStore');
         storeObj.load({
         params:{
         data:fileobj
         },
         callback: function(records,operation,success){
           console.log("send");
         },
         scope:this
         })
```

But its showing fileobj as undefined outside reader.onload function. So how to send this file along with its contents to server side? Is there any other way to get uploaded file in controller and send it to server. Please can someone guide me.

Comment: why not just submit the form???

Comment: Thanx sir for reply. When i am trying to submit form by adding code as-" buttons: [{
   xtype : 'button',
   fieldlabel:'upload', action:'upload', name:'upload',text: 'Upload',formBind:'true',
       handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'index.php/QuestionBank/Qbpaper/getFile',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');}});} }}]"

Comment: looks fine, whats the problem?

Comment: Its giving error as-" You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:"

Comment: where is the error, server, client? at what stage? upload, return?

Comment: My server side[PHP-Yii framework]code is as-"$fileName = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];
  $fp      = fopen($fileName, 'r');
  $content = fread($fp, filesize($fileName));
  $content = addslashes($content);
  fclose($fp);
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
   $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
  }"So now its giving me error as-Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: PHP notice Undefined index: upfile " Actually sir i am not getting how to access this file at server side. Please can you guide me..i will be very thankful for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to handle fileuplaod on php side, but the return response from the server needs to be text/html encoded
See the docs on this: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload

also example PHP fileupload script:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: thanx a lot sir...i will refer links you have provided.